# Grayed out options in the Oblivion launcher on Linux Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: steam, linux, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Why is the play button disabled/grayed out in the *TES IV: Oblivion* launcher? I'm using Linux, Lubuntu (20.04), and the game was downloaded from Steam. Using Proton 7.

[image: screenshot]

I've tried running the main .EXE file with Wine, but it just returns an error. I've also tried the solution suggested in this Reddit /r/linux_gaming post: [[FIX] Oblivion launcher has all options disabled/greyed out on Steam (Proton)](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/pijhgt/fix_oblivion_launcher_has_all_options/), but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you find the executable manually and start from there? I wonder if that would work.

Comment: Try the solution mentioned in this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/pijhgt/fix_oblivion_launcher_has_all_options/ Let me know if it works by @ tagging my username in a comment.

Comment: yes i did all that like 3 times and it didn't work @galacticninja

Comment: yes, but when i run the main .exe file with wine it just returns an error @Joachim

Comment: What error does it return?